# ASP.NET Uploaded File Deletion

Tags: c#, asp.net, file, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am very new to c# and ASP.NET and a friend has helped me out with my homework so far. The homework consists of a site to which I upload and also download files (to a folder called upload and also to the site). I want to have a function on which I delete the files. Could anyone give me the code for that based on my code? thank you so much, i have no idea how to  do that.

```
using FileUploadDownload.Models;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Security.Claims;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using TestAuth.Models;
using Aspose;

using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word;
using ceTe.DynamicPDF.Conversion;
using Syncfusion.DocIO.DLS;
using Syncfusion.DocToPDFConverter;
using Syncfusion.Pdf;
using Syncfusion.DocIO;
using Leadtools;
using Leadtools.Codecs;
using Leadtools.Document.Converter;
using Leadtools.Document.Writer;
using Leadtools.Ocr;

namespace TestAuth.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {

        List<AdminModel> adminModels = new List<AdminModel>();
        interface Iuser
        {
            public string username { get; set; }
            public string password { get; set; }
            void IsEqualTo();
        }
        class User : Iuser
        {
            public string username { get; set; }
            public string password { get; set; }



            public void IsEqualTo()
            {
                throw new NotImplementedException();
            }
        }
        class Admin : Iuser
        {
            public string username { get; set; }
            public string password { get; set; }
            public void IsEqualTo()
            {
                throw new NotImplementedException();
            }
        }
        
        public IActionResult Index()
        {

            return View();
        }

        public IActionResult Index1()
        {
            // Get files from the server
            var model = new FilesViewModel();
            foreach (var item in Directory.GetFiles(Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "upload")))
            {
                model.Files.Add(
                    new FileDetails { Name = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(item), Path = item });
            }
            return View(model);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult Index1(IFormFile[] files)
        {
            // Iterate each files
            foreach (var file in files)
            {
                // Get the file name from the browser
                var fileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);

                // Get file path to be uploaded
                var filePath = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "upload", fileName);







                // Check If file with same name exists and delete it
                if (System.IO.File.Exists(filePath))
                {
                    System.IO.File.Delete(filePath);
                }

                // Create a new local file and copy contents of uploaded file
                using (var localFile = System.IO.File.OpenWrite(filePath))
                using (var uploadedFile = file.OpenReadStream())

                {




                    uploadedFile.CopyTo(localFile);








                }

            }
            ViewBag.Message = "Files are successfully uploaded";

            // Get files from the server
            var model = new FilesViewModel();
            foreach (var item in Directory.GetFiles(Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "upload")))
            {
                model.Files.Add(
                    new FileDetails { Name = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(item), Path = item });

            }

            return View(model);
        }

        public async Task<IActionResult> Download(string filename)
        {
            if (filename == null)
                return Content("filename is not availble");

            var path = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "upload", filename);

            var memory = new MemoryStream();
            using (var stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open))
            {
                await stream.CopyToAsync(memory);
            }
            memory.Position = 0;
            return File(memory, GetContentType(path), Path.GetFileName(path));
        }
        private string GetContentType(string path)
        {
            var types = GetMimeTypes();
            var ext = Path.GetExtension(path).ToLowerInvariant();
            return types[ext];
        }

        private Dictionary<string, string> GetMimeTypes()
        {
            return new Dictionary<string, string>
            {
                {".txt", "text/plain"},
                {".pdf", "application/pdf"},
                {".doc", "application/vnd.ms-word"},
                {".docx", "application/vnd.ms-word"},
                {".xls", "application/vnd.ms-excel"},
                {".xlsx", "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet"},
                {".png", "image/png"},
                {".jpg", "image/jpeg"},
                {".jpeg", "image/jpeg"},
                {".gif", "image/gif"},
                {".csv", "text/csv"}
            };
        }

        
        

        public IActionResult Privacy()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpGet("denied")]
        public IActionResult Denied()
        {
            return View();
        }
        [Authorize(Roles ="Admin")]
        public IActionResult Secured()
        {
            return View();
        }
        [HttpGet("login")]
        public IActionResult Login(string returnUrl)
        {
            ViewData["ReturnURL"] = returnUrl;
            return View();
        }
        [HttpPost("login")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Validate(string username, string password, string returnUrl)
        {

            ViewData["ReturnUrl"] = returnUrl;
            List<Iuser> utilizatori = new List<Iuser>();
            utilizatori.Add(new User() { username = "username", password = "password" });
            utilizatori.Add(new Admin() { username = "bobitza", password = "28" });
            utilizatori.Add(new Admin() { username = "rares", password = "cretin" });

            foreach (Iuser user in utilizatori)
            {
                if(user.username==username && user.password==password)
                {
                    if (user is User)
                    {
                        var claims = new List<Claim>();
                        claims.Add(new Claim("username", username));
                        claims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, "User"));
                        var claimsIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
                        var claimsPrincipal = new ClaimsPrincipal(claimsIdentity);
                        await HttpContext.SignInAsync(claimsPrincipal);
                    } 
                    else if (user is Admin)
                    {
                        var claims = new List<Claim>();
                        claims.Add(new Claim("username", username));
                        claims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, "Admin"));
                        var claimsIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
                        var claimsPrincipal = new ClaimsPrincipal(claimsIdentity);
                        await HttpContext.SignInAsync(claimsPrincipal);
                    }    
                    
                }
            }
            
            

            
              
            TempData["Error"] = "Error. Username or Password is invlaid";
            return View("login");
        }
        [ResponseCache(Duration = 0, Location = ResponseCacheLocation.None, NoStore = true)]
        public IActionResult Error()
        {
            return View(new ErrorViewModel { RequestId = Activity.Current?.Id ?? HttpContext.TraceIdentifier });
        }
        public async Task<IActionResult> Logout()
        {
            await HttpContext.SignOutAsync();
            return Redirect("/");
        }
    }
}
```

and this is the index1 page

```
@*
    For more information on enabling MVC for empty projects, visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=397860
*@
@{
}
@*
    For more information on enabling MVC for empty projects, visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=397860
*@
@{
}
@model FileUploadDownload.Models.FilesViewModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Home Page";
}

<div class="text-left">
    <h2 style="margin-bottom:50px">Multiple File Upload</h2>
    @if (User.IsInRole("Admin"))
    {
        <!-- In order to post files to server we should use form with post method, also need to add multipart/form-data encoding.
               Otherwise the files will not sent to the server. -->

<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="files" multiple />
    
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
            <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">


                <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                        Alegeti categoria

                    </a>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Incepatori</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Avansati</a>
                        <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Admini</a>
                    </div>
                </li>

            </ul>
            <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
                <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
                <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
            </form>
        </div>
        <button type="submit">Upload</button>
    </nav>


</form>
    }
    <!-- To show the success message to the user  -->
    @if (ViewBag.Message != null)
    {
        <div class="alert alert-success" style="margin-top:50px">
            @ViewBag.Message
        </div>
    }

    <p style="margin-top: 50px">List of Files</p>
    <!-- Get all the files from the server -->
    <ul>


        @foreach (var item in Model.Files)
        {

            <li>
                <a asp-action="Download"
                   asp-route-filename="@item.Name">
                    @item.Name
                </a>
                

                
            </li>
        }
    </ul>

</div>
```

thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I would recommend you to separate your classes to different files, instead of everything in a single file.

For your question,

The same way you define an `[HttpGet]` attribute above a function to define it as a Get result, in HTTP we have `Delete` requests as well

Just create a method for deletion of files, something like this:

```
[HttpDelete]
public IActionResult Delete(string filename)
{
    if(System.IO.File.Exists(filename))
    {
        System.IO.File.Delete(filename);
    }
    return StatusCode(200);
}
```

Accordingly make a button for deletion of files in your user interface, which execute a delete command.

For more reading about http protocol visit [Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods)